# Why does a subclass of UIScrollView still scroll even if I override touchesMoved:withEvent:?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiscrollview, uikit

In iOS 4 I believed -touchesBegan:withEvent:, -touchesMoved:withEvent:, -touchesEnded:withEvent:, -touchesCancelled:withEvent: were the only methods available to implement in a view to handle touches.

But now when I override these methods like this:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    // not calling super. Doing nothing.
}
```

in a UIScrollView subclass, it still scrolls. How did they do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIScrollView uses a UIPanGestureRecognizer to scroll.  UIKit sends events to gesture recognizers through a private mechanism, separate from touchesBegan:withEvent: and related methods.

Comment: @MikhaloIvanokov UIPanGestureRecognizer is available from 3.2 onward.

Comment: UIScrollView uses a UIPanGestureRecognizer from iOS 3.2 on.  It just doesn't expose it directly as the panGestureRecognizer property until iOS 5.0.  If you look at the contents of the gestureRecognizers property on an earlier system, you will find it in that array.